# Access to page methods within section

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

Now sections are threaded as elements with some other elements in it
but this approach makes unable to use page methods inside sections:
`wait_until { login_button? }` will raise `NoMethodError: undefined method 'wait_until' for Watir::HTMLElement`

Is there anyway to access page methods inside section class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bug and should be raised as an issue for the project (https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues).

In the short term, you could work around the issue by calling `wait_until` directly against the Watir::Browser, which is returned by the page object's `browser` method:

`browser.wait_until { login_button? }`

Comment: nice, thanks for pointing to correct method! Will create bug report than.

Comment: The related project issue can be seen at https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/292